# GUI tool for watermarking photos and other images

Tags: image-processing, batch

Parents asked me if they can watermark their photos. By "watermark" I mean a small signature in a corner.

I made a [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/) scenario which they run they need. But it looks like Phatch breaks rotation EXIF tag and scaling is not very advanced.

So I'm looking for a tool that will allow non-technical people to watermark images.

Preferably, with automatic colour picker (it should choose invert colour for watermark).

OS X has a good example -- [Bronson Watermarker](http://quoteunquoteapps.com/bronson/).

Answer (score 1):

Why not try aPhoto (http://www.acein.cn/p/aphoto).
It can help your add watermarks easyly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gimp for that. [This YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIgoiecntM4.) shows how to do it.