# What program will create a watermark

Tags: photography

I'm looking for a graphics program that will permit me to make a watermark on photographs. Can anyone advise me on this? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124398/gui-tool-for-watermarking-photos-and-other-images

Answer (score 0):

Eg. `imagemagick`

Install with

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Usefull examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#watermarking).

Answer (score 0):

This question has always been number one for me and I've searched a lot for it. So I've found the perfect one, it's called PicsArt online mobile photo editor, where there is possibility to save your created cliparts. So whenever I open the app, I just select my watermark from saved files and put on the photo. Here is a tutorial on how to create your watermark: https://picsart.com/blog/post/how-to-create-watermark/